# Deploy directory Jboss Tools

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I have a problem with my jboss tools and the deploy directory.
I migrated my application from jboss 4 to jboss 5.1. So in my eclipse, I update jboss tools to the 3.0.3 version.

Before this version, I could set the deploy directory for my jboss server.
With the new version, I don't find where I can set this option.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: JBoss Tools 3.0.3 is about 4 years old, why not use something more recent ?

Comment: Because it's the version for eclipse ganymede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JBoss Tools server adapters (most WTP based server adapters does it this way btw.) you double click the server and there is a deployment destination on one or more of the tab pages in the server editor dependent on that particular server configuration ?

Comment: OMFG, I'm sorry. In the last version, everything was in only one tab and I don't see the new tab in the plugin :). Thanks for your help